# Check Box changes

Tags: c#, silverlight, checkbox

I have a check box, which when it is checked, fires a call to a web service.

This works fine as it is using a toggle function in a database which is updating as expected.

However my problem being I need the toggle function to be activated when a user unchecks the checkbox.

For some reason this does not seem to fire the toggle function in the database. I am using the following code -

```
 private void checkBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (checkCounter1 == 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            //WebService call
        }
        checkCounter1 = 1;
    }
```

I tried the checkBox_Changed event however this did not work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `SL` is more or less `WPF`. That's why i think in SL just like WPF there should be `Checked` and `UnChecked` event.

Assign Single event code to both these events (Since both take same arguments) like this

```
private void checkBox1_Checked_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.IsChecked)
    {
        //WebService call
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I do not know why this has been downvoted because Nikhil is absolutely right: you should handle the `Unchecked` event too to get when the user uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: This is correct: in Silverlight you must handle both `Checked` and `Unchecked` events in order to react properly to the user interaction with checkboxes. I almost always use the same handler too.

Comment: In the xaml for the checkbox I have Checked="checkBox1_Checked" and Unchecked="checkBox1_Checked", I do not fully understand your checkBox1_Checked_Unchecked, how can I implement this?

Comment: @Jambo: What you have done is perfect. Handler Name can be anything as long as it is taking right arguments here (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e). Here my handler name is `checkBox1_Checked_Unchecked` and your handler name is `checkBox1_Checked`. Now in your code when ever any of these two events (checked and unchecked) are fired , it should reach your `checkBox1_Checked` handler. What problem are you facing now?

Comment: I see thank you, perhaps I was unclear in this post, here I have restructured my problem with full code - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616020/using-checkboxes-in-silverlight

Answer (score 1):

Try the `CheckBox1.IsChecked` or `CheckBox1.Checked` property of the checkbox and see if they are checked in the event functions.